# valid_token? returns True even if access-token is not valid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, access-token, devise-token-auth

I am using '**devise_token_auth**' gem with **mongo** backend and when I try to check if token is valid with **valid_token?**(access_token,client) : it returns **True** no matter what the **access_token** is. Please guide me through this.

*note: **If I enter wrong client then it returns false but never returns false for wrong 'access-token'.**

Comment: In my opinion, it never return false for 'acces-token' after login successful because of session. Try don't store session.

Answer (score 0):

That's because tokens in batch requests are not being validated.
It appears to be a bug in the gem. 
It returns false when you change the client because it is no longer considered part of the same batch.